# Can I commit a Firestore batch write without waiting?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

## Overview

I want to create some document references in a Cloud Function and return them to be used in another document.  My app is time critical, so I don't want to wait for the batch to commit before returning the references.

### Current solution

I currently create the references and the destination document in one Cloud Function and then commit the whole batch.  This makes my code repetitive, as I need to create these references in other places, also.

### My question

If I omit the `.then` from the `batch.commit()` can I simply pass the references straight back and leave Cloud Firestore to write the documents in its own time?

I've created this test script, which works.  Is there a problem with this approach or should I always wait for a batch to finish writing before continuing code execution?

## My sample code

```
// Set the data to be written
let myData = {test: '123'};

// Create the document references and return them for future processing
let docRefs = writeData(myData);

// Write these references to a master document
myDoc = {
  name: 'A document containing references to other documents',
  doc0Ref: docRefs[0],
  doc1Ref: docRefs[1],
  doc2Ref: docRefs[2]
}
return db.collection('masterCollection').add(myDoc).then(response => {
  console.log('Success');
  return Promise.resolve();
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
  return Promise.reject(err);
});

// Create the batch and write the data
function writeData(myData) {
  let batch = firestore.batch();

  let doc1Ref = firestore.collection('test').doc();
  let doc2Ref = firestore.collection('test').doc();
  let doc3Ref = firestore.collection('test').doc();

  console.log(`doc1Ref: ${doc1Ref.id}, doc2Ref: ${doc2Ref.id}, doc3Ref = ${doc3Ref.id}`);

  batch.set(doc1Ref, myData);
  batch.set(doc2Ref, myData);
  batch.set(doc3Ref, myData);

  batch.commit(); // No .then to wait for the batch to be written
  return [doc1Ref, doc2Ref, doc3Ref];
}
```

Comment: Please say more about the context in which this code is running.  Is this in Cloud Functions?  Some other environment?  What are you going to do after you call this `writeData` function?

Comment: I've added some further code and clarified in the question, that this is running in Cloud Functions for Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Cloud Function doesn't deal with all asynchronous work correctly (typically, with promises), there is a very good chance that the work may not complete successfully.

For HTTP triggers, you must only send your final response to the client *after* all the pending work is complete.

For all other types of triggers, you must return a promise that resolves only after all the async work in that function is complete.

What you have right now is a "dangling" promise that's not being handled according to these rules.  If you're using ESLint or TSLint to check your code, the linter will likely detect this and complain about it.

Comment: Thanks, Doug.  " ...you must return a promise that resolves only after all the async work in that function is complete." <-- That's exactly the answer I needed.

Comment: For further clarity (in case someone else stumbles across this), I've added the final Promise resolution in my sample code.